# line replacement in a file in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I want to search for the entire line and replace the line with 1 or more lines .

for eg Hi I m there .

I have to replace it with  these 2 lines

Hi I m there

Arun is here

Basically what I m trying to do is Insert a new line after the matching line .since I m not sure of line numbers ,thought I would serach for the line after which it should be placed and just replace this line with 2 lines .is it posssible ? the code i used var1 and var are picked up from a csv file and f is the file name

```
"s@$Var1@$Var2@g" "$f"
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  [`sed(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) or [`awk(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) would be good tools to use.

Comment: How to do we insert a carrage return ? using SED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 echo -e "Hi Im here\nLinetwo\nLine3" \
 | sed '/Hi Im here/a\
      Arun is here 

 '
```

**output**

```
 Hi Im here
 Arun is here
 Linetwo
 Line3
```

This is old-fashioned sed syntax. It should work on any of them.

Note that no space or tab chars allowed after `a\`, AND that the "a"ppend input is terminated by a blank line, hence the

```
 Arun is here
 (this is a blank line here, followed by the closing single quote for sed)
 '
```

IHTH

Comment: I stored these values in 2 variables and stored Var1=Hi Im here var2=a\Arun is here and used sed as sed -i "s@$Var1@$Var2@g" "$f" where $f is a filename .my out put was it replace hi Im here with aArun is here

Comment: Please edit your original question with information that will help us give you a working answer. Please edit your question to include the output of `sed --version` and `uname`. Please include sample input, required output, the code you have done so far AND any error messages your are getting. Note that my solution does NOT rely on s/srch/repl pattern from sed. Good luck.